# Passing data between views in Django

Tags: django

I have a FormView (currently a WizardView as I have multiple forms) which takes input from the (anonymous) user and passes the cleaned data to be used in a request to an external api.

However I'm not clear how best to pass the data recieved from one view to the next view?

The data received from the api is to be displayed in the next view. 
(If the data was held internally (rather than in an external api) I would probably try a ListView with the relevant parameters passed from the FormView to the ListView via a session)

However the api returned data will have many pages of data.
What's the best way to manage this in django? (This doesn't need to be async as the returned data is required before the user can proceed.)

```
class QuotesWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [QUOTES_TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
        postcode = form_dict['postcode'].cleaned_data['postcode']
        service = form_dict['service'].cleaned_data['service']
        usage = form_dict['usage'].cleaned_data['usage']

        usage = convert_usage(usage)

        # get data from external api
        data = get_quotes(postcode, usage_ofgem, service_type)

        # redirect to quotes page - how to manage transfer of data?
        return redirect('quotes')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar approach in a module, also not surprisingly with address data.

I've chosen to store the results in the database, so I've created a model for it. One reason is that number of calls have a price, so each call I'm not making, I'm saving money. Another is that I'm not bound by the whims of the remote API: My API is consistent for the browser and Django views and if something changes remotely, I have to fix it only in one place.

The crux is to make a QuerySet in which you override the `get` method and in your case also the filter method in a similar way:

```
class PostcodeApiQuerySet(QuerySet):
# fields, other methods
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(PostcodeApiQuerySet, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            self._validate_lookup_kwargs(kwargs)
            pc = self._get_field_lookup_value('pc', kwargs)
            house_nr = self._get_field_lookup_value('house_nr', kwargs)
            house_nr_add = self._get_field_lookup_value('house_nr_add', kwargs)
            try:
                address = self._fetch_one(
                    pc, house_nr, house_nr_add=house_nr_add
                )
            except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
                raise self.model.DoesNotExist(e.args[0])
            except KeyError as e:
                raise self.model.DoesNotExist(e.args[0])
            except ValueError as e:
                raise self.model.DoesNotExist(e.args[0])

            street = self._handle_foreign_for_address(address)
            instance = self.model(street=street, **address)
            instance.full_clean()
            instance.save()
            instance.refresh_from_db()
            return instance
```

The methods called here that are not included, deal with the remote API and mapping of fields to API filters, but it should give you a general idea. The `filter` method will be a bit more complex, as you will have to figure out what you don't have and as such what you need to fetch remotely.

Once you've got this done, you can reduce your pages of data to a list of ID's, which should easily fit in a session. Then you can use ListView and override `get_queryset()` to teach it about the list of ID's to get from the session.

### EDIT

So the flow is:

1. FormView (GET): render selection form
2. FormView (POST), in form_valid: Apply filters to overridden filter method of the custom queryset (Also see [Manager.from_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset)) and store ID's in session
3. FormView (POST), in form_valid [creates redirect](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/FormMixin/) to success_url
4. ListView (GET) invokes `get_queryset` which you've taught to [deal with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in) ID's in session

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that's useful. What's the method you use to pass the relevant parameters (eg postcode, housenumber) to your listview from your previous view (eg formview - if using data from user).  That's the part I'm still missing.

Comment: It depends how much data it is. I'd probably use a POST to be in the safe side and in the FormView's `form_valid` handle the bit above, store id's in session and define the success_url as the url that invokes the `ListView` (so it gets redirected). Since you're possibly modifying the database with newly fetched items, POST also fits in that respect.

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this:

1. Pass the data using `GET` params while redirecting. This way the resultant view would be cacheable and stateless. **(recommended)**
2. Use [`django sessions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/). Add the variable to session, which can be 
      retrived globally. Sessions act as global variables, so use them 
      only as last resort.
3. Use [`django messages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/) if you want to store variables in session only for next view.

Comment: Please see requirements: "many pages of data". And messages uses sessions. Finally, the data is fetched by an API on the server. So at minimum in your recommended method, you'd need a redirect.

Comment: Point 2 is *nonsense*. Sessions do not "act as global variables".

Comment: @DanielRoseman I believe they do share all characteristics of global variables. I'm not denying the usefulness, they are indeed helpful for some use cases, say maintaining logged in user data. However session variables are very hard to track and maintain. I have seen people adding data to session in one view, and later getting it out in a completely unrelated view.

Comment: It's never completely unrelated. It's tied to the visitor. Global variables are tied to nothing.

Comment: @Melvyn Ok, there are global only per user, but that doesn't mean they aren't global. Session variables carry all the issues which global variables does. They increases the coupling among views, and make testing a nightmare. They furthermore renders the page un-cacheable.